# Changing frame rate from 24 to 60 breaks projected in video sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

Video sequence overlaps when I change frame rate from 24 to 60. All soft slices extend and overlaps, so I got multiple audio strips playing at the same time and I don;t know how to solve this issue.

[image]

[image: Video Sequence]

[image]